# Ember.js setting application property on load

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to fetch the current logged in user via my REST API and then set it as a property of the ApplicationController. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        var self = this;
        App.User.findCurrent().then(function(user) {
          self.set('currentUser', user);
        });
    }
});

App.User = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.User.reopenClass({
    findCurrent: function() {
        return $.getJSON('/api/v1/users/current').then(
            function(response) {
                return response.user;
            }
        );
    }
});
```

When I check the Chrome network tab, I see there's a call to the API and the JSON is returned, but when I try to access e.g. `{{currentUser.name}}` in my application template (or a partial of it), it doesn't return the name. No errors are given as well.

But in the application template it doesn't return it.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

**Edit**

When I create another controller, e.g. `HelpController` and visit `/help`, then `{{currentUser.name}}` does return the username:

```
App.HelpController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentUser')
});
```

**Edit 2**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm actually trying to use `{{currentUser.name}}` from a partial (`{{partial 'sidebar'}}`), but that shouldn't change anything, because that's the same scope, right?

**Edit 3**

I noticed something very strange. When I call `{{currentUser.name}}` in my application template (which is not what I want btw), then it also works in the `{{partial 'sidebar'}}`.

**Edit 4**

As per request:

```
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6 ember.js?body=1:361
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 ember.js?body=1:361
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.0
```

Comment: I created a jsbin and works, please give a look http://jsbin.com/ucanam/487/edit.

Comment: That is very strange. It's indeed exactly like I do!

Comment: Right. Can you add the versions of handlebars, ember and jquery, in your question? This is logged in browser console. When the app init.

Comment: Question has been updated with the debug information.

Comment: Thanks. I received Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0.0, COMPILER_REVISION expected: 4, got: 3 - Please note: Builds of master may have other COMPILER_REVISION values.

Comment: Try to use the lastes version of handlebars http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js. I think that ember lastest isn't compatible with handlebars 1.0.0-rc.4

Comment: I modified your JS Bin with the versions of Ember, Handlebars and jQuery that I'm using, and that works as well. It's so confusing, pff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the correct place to put this logic. You can use the route hooks `model` and `afterModel` on the `ApplicationRoute`, to do this easily. In general in ember loading of data is done in the routes hooks. This allows the router pause while loading so by the time your controller and templates come into play, they are working with loaded data.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = function() {
  model: function() {
    return App.User.findCurrent();
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    App.set('currentUser', model)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it doesn't seem to work. Check this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ewasoq/1/edit

Comment: The issue you facing is you are using `{{currentUser.name}}` in your template. You need to refer to it as `{{model.name}}` or `{{App.currentUser.name}}` etc. Or create a `currentUser` computed property.

Comment: Exactly! It works now. Thank you so much! I still have a lot to learn about Ember. I think I'll go through the guides/docs again.